# SQL developer query result keyboard shortcut

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is there a shortcut in SQL Developer to hide and display the query result like a Ctrl+R in SSMS ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, more or less.

Shift + ALT + F8

Then…

- HOME to go full-screen output
- END to go full-screen editor
- UP/DOWN arrows to move the splitter

[Demo here.](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2019/06/hide-or-full-screen-query-results/)

Comment: Ok thank you, is there a way to escape the mode "Shift + Alt + F8" because "ESC" doesn't work. Or is there a way to make it simple like a ctrl+r to display and hide ?

Comment: I try to find a way without using the mouse

Comment: just hit alt+shift+f8 again

Comment: Does not work. Maybe it's because of my version (21.4.2.018)?

Comment: I just tried it in v22.2...worked for me. Some things just require a mouse for optimal GUI experience and this is one of those things, probably.